# Weird Error in XSLT 2.0 [SXXP0003]

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I've been dealing with XSLT 2.0 in the past day, trying to parse a plain text file.
apparently I couldn't even get to the part where I actually get it working, at the moment, the xsl doesn't have to do something, just to load properly in saxonb-xslt processor.

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions"  version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match='/'>
<add_adverts>
<Body>
<Envelope>
<Advert>
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(unparsed-text('A2.blm'), '\r?\n')">
 <fff>?</fff>
</xsl:for-each>
</Advert>
</Envelope>
</Body>
</add_adverts>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How I run it:

```
saxonb-xslt -s:A2.blm -xsl:eraxsl.xsl -o:test.xml
```

the blm file is a plain text file, first line is: #HEADER# last line is #END# there is a line in it named #DATA# from which I want to parse until the end.
each record is separated by ^.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you passing the text file as input source in the commmand line?

Comment: Consider to provide minimal but complete samples allowing us to easily reproduce the problem? Which version of Saxon is that exactly?

Comment: See my answer for a complete solution. Your problem is that the relative URI cannot be resolved successfully -- the file must be in the same directory as the XSLT stylesheet. Or, you need to provide an absolute URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I do not repro this problem at all -- I have created the "A2.blm" file in the same directory as the XSLT stylesheet. The transformation works as expected.**

This error is from the XML parser, not from the XSLT processor. Most probably you have provided as source XML file something that is not a well-formed XML document (or is completely missing).

**Most probably the file "A2.blm" cannot be found or accessed -- check well**.

In order of this file to be found, it must be in the same directory your stylesheet file is.

From the **[XSLT 2.0 W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unparsed-text)**:

"The unparsed-text function reads an external resource (for example, a file) and returns its contents as a string.

*The $href argument must be a string in the form of a URI. The URI must contain no fragment identifier, and must identify a resource that can be read as text. **If the URI is a relative URI, then it is resolved relative to the base URI from the static context***.
"

And most importantly:

"*Note:
If a different base URI is appropriate (for example, when resolving a relative URI read from a source document) then the relative URI should be resolved using the resolve-uriFO function before passing it to the unparsed-text function*."

Here is a proof that the rest of your transformation works as intended:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions"  version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match='/'>
        <add_adverts>
            <Body>
                <Envelope>
                    <Advert>
                        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\r?\n')">
                            <fff>?</fff>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </Advert>
                </Envelope>
            </Body>
        </add_adverts>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>1&#xA;2&#xD;&#xA;3&#xA;</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<add_adverts xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions">
   <Body>
      <Envelope>
         <Advert>
            <fff>?</fff>
            <fff>?</fff>
            <fff>?</fff>
            <fff>?</fff>
         </Advert>
      </Envelope>
   </Body>
</add_adverts>
```

Comment: Again, amazing answer. btw, do my input file (the one I want to transform to XML) must have tags (in your example <t>...</t>), cant I use XSLT to transform regular text files to XML?

Comment: You can use anything -- I usually use `<t/>`. Or you may specify on the command-line an initial template name (check the syntax), in which case you do not specify source XML file at all.

Answer (score 2):

The `-s:` parameter to saxon-xslt specifies the source document which has to be in xml format I think. In your example you don't need this source since you specify the file name in your template. The solution would be to remove the source parameter and to specify a named template instead of the match as the starting point:

```
<xsl:template name="main">
    <add_adverts>...<add_adverts>
</xsl:template>


saxonb-xslt -xsl:eraxsl.xsl -o:test.xml -it:main
```